# Issue with Hibernate collections

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to Hibernate and I am trying to create a mapping between my POJO classes Person and Event. A Person has a set of Events as shown here:

POJO for Event class and its mapping file:

```
public class Event {
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private Date date;
    // setter & getter methods
}

<class name="Event" table="EVENTS">
    <id name="id" column="EVENT_ID">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="title" />
    <property name="date" type="timestamp" column="EVENT_DATE" />      
 </class>
```

POJO for Person and its mapping:

```
public class Person {
        private Long id;
private int age;
private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private Set<Event> events = new HashSet<Event>();
    // setter & getter methods
}

<class name="Person" table="PERSON_NEW">
    <id name="id" column="PERSON_ID">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="firstname" />
<property name="age" />
    <property name="lastname" />    
    <set name="events" table="PERSON_EVENTS">
        <key column="PERSON_ID" />
        <many-to-many column="EVENT_ID" class="Event" />
    </set>
</class>
```

Sample program that creates an Event, a Person and mapping the Event to the Person:

```
public class EventManager {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventManager mgr = new EventManager();

        Long eventId = mgr.createAndStoreEvent("Hibernate");
        Long personId = mgr.createAndStorePerson("Smith");
        mgr.addPersonToEvent(personId, eventId);
        System.out.println("Added person " + personId + " to event " + eventId);
        HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().close();
    }

    private Long createAndStoreEvent(String title) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Event theEvent = new Event();
        theEvent.setTitle(title);
        Long eventId = (Long) session.save(theEvent);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return eventId;
    }

    private Long createAndStorePerson(String firstName) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setFirstname(firstName);
        Long personId = (Long) session.save(person);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return personId;
    }

    private void addPersonToEvent(Long personId, Long eventId) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Person aPerson = (Person) session.load(Person.class, personId);
        Event anEvent = (Event) session.load(Event.class, eventId);
        aPerson.getEvents().add(anEvent);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

When I run this program I am getting below logs with exception saying parent key not found:

```
Hibernate: select hibernate_sequence.nextval from dual
Hibernate: insert into EVENTS (EVENT_DATE, title, EVENT_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select hibernate_sequence.nextval from dual
Hibernate: insert into PERSON_NEW (age, firstname, lastname, PERSON_ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select person0_.PERSON_ID as PERSON1_1_0_, person0_.age as age1_0_, person0_.firstname as firstname1_0_, person0_.lastname as lastname1_0_ from PERSON_NEW person0_ where person0_.PERSON_ID=?
Hibernate: select events0_.PERSON_ID as PERSON1_1_1_, events0_.EVENT_ID as EVENT2_2_1_, event1_.EVENT_ID as EVENT1_0_0_, event1_.EVENT_DATE as EVENT2_0_0_, event1_.title as title0_0_ from PERSON_EVENTS events0_, EVENTS event1_ where events0_.EVENT_ID=event1_.EVENT_ID and events0_.PERSON_ID=?
Hibernate: insert into PERSON_EVENTS (PERSON_ID, EVENT_ID) values (?, ?)
02:18:59,095  WARN SqlExceptionHelper:143 - SQL Error: 2291, SQLState: 23000
02:18:59,095 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:144 - ORA-02291: integrity constraint (LEARNING.FK4A94943B0A1327A) violated - parent key not found

Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (LEARNING.FK4A94943B0A1327A) violated - parent key not found

    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
```

I am using Hibernate 3.x, please help me where I made mistake in this code? From my Oracle database I can see that the records for Event and Person are stored successfully but the joining table is empty as I got an exception in running this program.

Comment: For one thing, please use Type constraints when using a Collection such as a Set rather than leaving it as a raw collection type. Also, you do not have to create the Set of events in the Person class in the instance variable declaration (we should use the getters and setters).

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `events set` entry of the mapping file for `Person` to this:

```
<set name="events" table="PERSON_EVENTS" cascade="save-update">
        <key column="PERSON_ID" />
        <many-to-many column="EVENT_ID" class="Event" unique="true"/>
</set>
```

where the `unique="true"` attribute of `many-to-many` element changes the multiplicity from `many-to-many` to `one-to-many`.

And `cascade="save-update"` is used to achieve transitive persistence; with this when you create an instance of `Event` and add it to the set of `events` in `Person`, it will become persistent along with the `Person`. You don't have to make a `Event` persistent explicitly by calling `save()` on the `Session` interface. The `cascade` attribute tells Hibernate to make any `new Event` instance persistent (that is, save it in the database) if the `Event` is referenced by a persistent `Person`.

With these changes in place, you can save a `Person` along with a set of `events` as below:

```
Event event = new Event();
event.setTitle(...);
event.setDate(...);

Set<Event> events = new HashSet<Event>();
events.add(event);

Person p = new Person();
p.setAge(...);
...
p.setEvents(events);

session.save(p);
```